# Which mushroom species is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, mushroom

Which type of mushroom is this? Hope the image has enough quality to allow answering the question.

Following community rules...

- Images: please find below
- Location: West-Northern Germany
- Size - about 7 cm height, 5 width
- Prior research: very hard to undestand which species is this, therefore asking here. Maybe this could be a *Gymnopus peronatus* - but here the stem is darker.
- Specific characteristic: hollow stem

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info including the specific info on mushrooms as well as all the other more generic requirements.

Comment: If you had a good book, you could identify that very fast. the particular features are, irregular stem, irregular widely spaced gills, no viscous pellicle on top, tan on top, grey gills, here is a identifier which might help: http://www.mycokey.org/agaric1.shtml?language=uk&localLanguage=uk&searchMode=full&atlasmode=false&r=132029.27384465246 there are other identifiers too. it looks quite unsuitable for a home ID for culinary, i've seen those already though, very common, i think they are related to the bright yellow ones with the grey gills.

Comment: google searching by image is giving me [Russula integra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russula_integra).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right that it is a Gymnopus, It's difficult to know which one. There's also [Gymnopus Fusipes](http://www.pharmanatur.com/Mycologie/Collybia%20fusipes.htm). For a difficult ID, it's best to have a cross section, a description of the scent, compare the color under the youngest specimens, as the gills often change from very light to very dark with age.

Comment: Could you please provide some sort of support for the ID method claims you make? (I understand that they're likely based on your own experience. However, to be most helpful, providing reputable support that other users can explore really would increase the broader utility of your answer). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Genus Amillaria species may be mellea

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Biology.SE. For responses to species identification questions, please be sure to include more information about your proposed ID, which may include common characteristics that resemble the OP, species distribution, and other general info. At least one picture is also strongly desired, with a link to its source. Thanks.

Comment: @atxgis citing reputable sources is also strongly advised, especially when referring to species IDs (since so much misinformation exists online!). Thanks

Answer (score -2):

It has characteristics of a Chantrelle ; I would start there to identify it. Chantrelles are usually more orange or yellow but I have mushrooms in my yard that look very similar to the picture and after checking several references I believe it is a Chantrelle .

Comment: Definitely not a chantrelle, that should have decurrent ridges.

Comment: I never downmark but that's the worst ID i ever read, especially because it's dangerous. A chantrelle has round gill folds, and a trumpet gill base, it's smaller, doesnt go translucent or grey. There is a false chanterelle that is dangerous which has more in common with that mushroom. http://www.gallowaywildfoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/trumpet-v-sinuous-e1474988442548-900x1024.jpg common chanterelle: http://tcpermaculture.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/C_cibarius02.jpg

Comment: I was concentrating too much on the branching of the gills.However , been eating wild mushrooms for 40 years and I am still here.